# magento integration with erp and crm

Tags: magento, integration, crm, erp

How to integrate Magento with ERP and CRM and which are erp's and crm's which is best integrated with Magento?

And how easy it is to do this integration?

Answer (score 2):

See [magento integration with erp and crm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904602/magento-integration-with-erp-and-crm) for how to do it. The easiest ERP / CRM systems will be ones that you can set up to pull information from Magento periodically and put it back in over webservices. Open source solutions (where you can monkey with the code) will work out better than closed source solutions, especially ones where you don't have direct database access.

As for ease, it depends on how much data will be transferred. Moving orders back to ERP, or moving customers to CRM is not difficult, but keeping everything highly synchronized is another story.

If you have other questions, please be more specific and I'll be happy to help.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: The link that you have referenced, goes to this page. How is this helpful?

Comment: @Phorce Honestly five years ago I'm guessing it went somewhere else. After so long I have no idea. It sure does seem like a crap answer _now_, though, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

InSync presents 'SBOeConnect', e-Commerce Connector for SAP Business One. SBOeConnect gives the flexibility for seamless integration between Magento Commerce with leading ERP Business Solution SAP Business One. SBOeConnect provides a real time synchronization between these two platforms, eliminating manual data entry and reducing data redundancy.

For more please visit at http://sboeconnect.com

Regards,
Soumen.
Team sboeconnect.com

Answer (score 1):

I think you may try to use Web Service of the Magento. Write a "bridge" program to transfer/update data from Magento and the ERP system. There should be API for most of the ERP system.

Here is the link for Magento web service. Basically it is very convenient.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/introduction

And most of the time, you're supposed to handle order related information daily, you can setup cron job to run the "bridge" program then.

Answer (score -1):

Try openbravo its an erp. They have a built-in connector for it to Magento. You can synchronize customers, products and sales order from Magento into Openbravo ERP. It can be scheduled by time or by frequency to be executed. The documentation for it can be had from [here](http://forge.openbravo.com/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Magento).

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. Links without explanation is no good, as links become broken over time. (And this URL returned 404)